# How do I change the VGA resolution for the non-graphical TTYs?

Tags: tty, vga

I have 200 chars in width, and only 2 old eyes. That's too much of too little :)

I've seen various answers on these forums, but none of them seemed to help me.

```
:~$ sudo hwinfo --framebuffer | grep Mode
Model: "Intel(R)Sandybridge Mobile Graphics Controller"
SNIP! 
Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits
SNIP!
```

Is the resolution I'm going for

(I've cut away a lot of resolutions there)

I'm on Oneiric which of course means grub2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting a larger font:

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-Terminus32x16.psf.gz
```

This sets a nice, large, readable font. Check /usr/share/consolefonts for available fonts, each one has different point sizes.

Oh, and this works on a per-console basis so you can have a different font for each TTY.

Comment: ah - that's an even easier way of doing it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is now set by grub

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

and look for the following lines

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Uncomment the last line, and set your desired resolution.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
```

Then update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution

Comment: While your answer is indeed the 'canonical' answer ... it doesn't help me.

The grub bootloader does change resolution, but not the <Ctrl><Alt>F1...F6 TTYs

They are still too small ... no change in them ...

Comment: ok - i give up, i wanted to dutifully update my answer - but users who aren't 300 questions old are hassled in a manner that is just too much.
HERES THE INFO

The right question is: How do I get a bigger font size in the TTYs

The answer to that question I found here: **http://askubuntu.com/questions/86827/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-making-my-ttys-a-nice-resolution**

    sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup.


From that program you can choose font and font-size

I haven't booted yet, but you can check in the TTY by using the command

    setupcon

To see if you hit something you can use

Comment: update my question I meant

Comment: @user42584 post that as an answer. You will soon have enough reputation to make adjustments, it is a hassle at first, but be patient.

Comment: I cannot post an answer yet ...

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the kernel from setting the mode using the "nomodeset"-kernel Parameter:

edit /etc/default/grub and add:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Once you have saved the changes, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot - and the screen resolution will stay 640x480 for all ttys (Tested on Ubunutu Server 14.04)